# How to implement CMake configure_file command in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I think everybody knows [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/configure_file.html) excellent CMake command:

```
configure_file( 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.h.cmake 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version.h 
)
```

But I have to implement that in Makefile. Could you please help me? How to do it?

Configuration file (version.h) is very simple:

```
#ifndef _VERSION_H_ 
#define _VERSION_H_ 

#define VERSION_MAJOR @VERSION_MAJOR@ 
#define VERSION_MINOR @VERSION_MINOR@ 
#define VERSION_BUILD @VERSION_BUILD@ 
#define VERSION_REVISION @VERSION_REVISION@ 

#endif // _VERSION_H_
```

Comment: If you want to use `configure_file` from cmake, why don't you just use it, instead of reimplementing the wheel? Anyway, take a look at [configure scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script)

Comment: @wasthishelpful for some reason we have to move from cmake to makefile.

Comment: Reconsider your reason :) XY problem

Answer (score 2):

This won't work. Well it might be, but it will be a hassle. These config.h files are made to communicate the result from a configure tool (configure from Autotools, CMake etc.) to the compiler.

When you use Makefiles, you can simply attach necessary flags or variables to the C(++) compiler call (with `-D`). There is no need to add the complexity of a config.h.